# How to parse this data format in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following data after API request and not sure how to get `link` from the data. Anyone help?

```
#<ExampleApi::Results::GetTemporaryLinkResult:0x00007f9edf280c78 
@data={"metadata"=>{"name"=>"test.jpg", "id"=>"id:xxxxxxxx",
"link"=>"https://example.com/apitl/1/AnHQ08SIuxh9cdXL1q-EpG8L"}>
```

Comment: Where is the class `ExampleApi::Results::GetTemporaryLinkResult` defined?

Answer (score 2):

Its a Hash and you can retrieve by the key

```
@data["metadata"]["link"]
```

**Edited**

```
class ExamplerResult
      attr_accessor :data
      def initialize()
        @data = {"metadata"=>{"name"=>"test.jpg", "id"=>"id:xxxxxxxx", "link"=>"https://example.com/apitl/1/AnHQ08SIuxh9cdXL1q-EpG8L"}}
      end
end

data = ExamplerResult.new.data
data["metadata"]["link"]
```

Comment: Hi, `object = #<ExampleApi::Results::GetTemporaryLinkResult:0x00007f9edf280c78 
@data={"metadata"=>{"name"=>"test.jpg", "id"=>"id:xxxxxxxx", "link"=>"https://example.com/apitl/1/AnHQ08SIuxh9cdXL1q-EpG8L"}>`, then object@data["metadata"]["link"] ?

Comment: Hi @jvillian, I am still getting `"*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `data for #<ExampleApi::Results::GetTemporaryLinkResult:0x00007f9edf280c78>` but when I run object it returns the value I commented above

Answer (score 0):

For Hash you can use `dig` from ruby 2.3
`@data.dig("metadata", "link")` to retrieve (nested) keys

Reference link
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig